# Routing Error: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to set up routes for a mobile API, which should have a versioned api-path. I already could make the mobile Auth work, which is implemented in a separate Controller *AuthController* located in **/controllers/api/v1/mobile/**.

Usage example:

```
myapp.com/api/v1/mobile/auth
```

But now I want to register my existing ressources-Controllers to this path-pattern as additional api-routes. Concrete: this would be the *TasksController* located at **/controllers/tracker/tasks_controller.rb**. So I added a *mobile route* to the routes-definition:

```
# routes.rb
namespace :tracker, path: 'timetracking' do
  resources :tasks, 'jobs'
end

namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    namespace :mobile do
      resources :auth, :only => [:create, :destroy]

      namespace :tracker do    #added mobile route
        resource :tasks, controller: 'tracker/tasks', as: :mobile_tasks
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But when I call **myapp.com/api/v1/mobile/tracker/tasks** it results in an error-message:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant Api::V1::Mobile::Tracker
```

I especially added the alias **:mobile_tasks** to this route, to avoid any conflicts with the original tasks-route above. Any ideas, how to set the controller properly for this route?

**Update#1**

Defining this route as a scope instead of a namespace, didn't work aswell.

```
scope "/api/v1/mobile/tracker" do
    resources :tasks, controller: 'tracker/tasks', as: :mobile_tasks
end
```

But this time, it didn't even resolve the route-path itself.

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/mobile/tracker/tasks"
```

I assume it might be a problem, that my additional mobile-api route tries to point to a completely different namespace *tracker*.

Comment: Was running into similar issues, and actually I just had to restart `rails server`. I guess it is necessary for it to pick up changes in namespaces and all. Putting it there in case other people end up here from Google!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing you should use scope instead of namespace.

If you want to route `/admin/posts` to `PostsController` (without the `Admin:: module prefix`), you could use:

```
scope "/admin" do
  resources :posts, :comments
end
```

Comment: Hi Krists, thanks for your answer. I updated my question-text with the rails-output regarding your suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried `rake routes` command to print out all defined routes in match order and names? It should help you debug this problem.

Comment: thx for the good hint with `rake routes`. helped me to work this out :)

Comment: @loybert - if you've solved your problem, please follow up !  either update youe question, add a comment to the correct answer or even add a new answer

Comment: hi @ivar. As far as I remember there was an namespace-block too much, because it already had set the parent-namespace implicitly, so running `rake routes` helped me to see the malformed route path, which was looking kinda **/mobile/api/v1/tracker/tracker/tasks**.

Sorry for my comment isn't that accurate, but in case you opened a question yourself, I would take a look. :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding this answer to get clarity on namespace & scope.

When you use namespace, it will prefix the URL path for the specified resources, and try to locate the controller under a module named in the same manner as the namespace.

```
# config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts, only: [:index]
end

# rake routes
Prefix Verb URI    Pattern                   Controller#Action
admin_posts GET    /admin/posts(.:format)    admin/posts#index
```

When we add scope, it will just map the controller action for the given scope patterns. No need to define controller under any module.

```
# config/routes.rb
scope :admin do
  resources :posts, only: [:index]
end

# rake routes
Prefix Verb URI    Pattern                   Controller#Action
admin_posts GET    /admin/posts(.:format)    posts#index
```

Note that, controller is just posts controller without any module namespace.

If we add a `path` option to scope it will map to the controller with the path option specified as follows

```
# config/routes.rb
scope module: 'admin', path: 'admin' do
  resources :posts, only: [:index]
end

# rake routes
Prefix Verb URI    Pattern                   Controller#Action
admin_posts GET    /admin/posts(.:format)    admin/posts#index
```

Note that the controller now is under admin module.

Now, if we want to change the name of path method to identify resource, we can add `as` option to scope.

```
# config/routes.rb
namespace module: 'admin', path: 'admin', as: 'root' do
  resources :posts, only: [:index]
end

# rake routes
Prefix Verb URI    Pattern                  Controller#Action
root_posts GET    /admin/posts(.:format)    admin/posts#index
```

You can see the change in the Prefix Verb.

Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but still might be helpful:

```
scope '/v1' do  
  resources :articles, module: 'v1'
end
```

controller

```
# app/controller/v1/articles_controller.rb
class V1::ArticlesController < ApplicationController

end
```

Now you should be able to access this url:

http://localhost:3000/v1/articles